# undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) ruby

Tags: ruby, powerpoint, scorm

trying to build a pptx to scorm converter. I get an error NoMethodError Undefined method `+' for NilClass. I guess it may be due to a defined method. any idea on how i can remove this error ?

```
dir = ARGV.shift
dest = ARGV.shift
pptx = dir + "/presentation.pptx"
lis = []`enter code here`
STDERR.puts "Copy template => #{dest}"
FileUtils.cp_r "template", dest
Dir["#{dir}/*.PNG"].each do |file|
  STDERR.puts "Copy #{file} => #{dest}/img"
  FileUtils.cp file, "#{dest}/img/"
  STDERR.puts "Creating thumb #{file} => #{dest}/img/thumb"
  name = file.split(/\//).last
  system "/usr/bin/convert", "-scale", "200x", file, "#{dest}/img/thumb/#{name}"
  lis.push name
end

ordered = lis.sort_by { |x| x[/\d+/].to_i }
```

Comment: do you have some code? The error probably contains a line of the code that causes the error.

Comment: It means that `dir` is `nil`. You are probably calling that script without passing the required command line arguments.

Comment: how do i go about doing it i am quite new to ruby i believe the problem lies in the defining method used

Comment: @petergrill how do you run that Ruby code?

Comment: @Stefan using command prompt

Comment: You have to pass `dir` and `dest` as arguments: `ruby script.rb dir dest` (where `script.rb` is your script's name, `dir` is the directory for `presentation.pptx` and `dest` is the output directory)

Comment: thank you! @Stefan one last question, now there is another error does it mean i have to place a .pptx file somewhere in the correct directory?

C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubyzip-2.3.0/lib/zip/file.rb:106:in `initialize': File dir/presentation.pptx not found (Zip::Error)
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubyzip-2.3.0/lib/zip/file.rb:121:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubyzip-2.3.0/lib/zip/file.rb:121:in `open'
        from pptx_to_scorm.rb:74:in `<main>'

Comment: @petergrill the error message `File dir/presentation.pptx not found` seems self explanatory – you provided `dir` as the first argument but there's no file "dir/presentation.pptx", hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

## DIR is nil

If you debug your code as follows:

```rb
puts dir.nil? # true
```

So, in order to run this code you **must** provide the ruby shell with 2 arguments, as follows:

```
ruby test.rb DIRECTORY_NAME DESTINATION_NAME
```